# How to get a text between nodes

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I have a problem with extracting text between nodes.It shows me the entire `span` node.I would like to get value of hours e.g 4:45;5:15 e.t.c.

```
var html = @"https://programtv.onet.pl/";
        HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
        var htmldoc=web.Load(html);
        var findhours = htmldoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id='boxTV1']//div[@class='hours']//span[@class='hour']");

        if (findhours != null)
        {
            foreach (var x in findhours )
            {
                Console.WriteLine(x.OuterHtml);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("node = null");
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
```

[Application window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBQOP.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use the `InnerText` property of your `HtmlNode` object. Checkout the following [documentation](http://html-agility-pack.net/inner-text).

```
foreach (var x in findhours )
{
    Console.WriteLine(x.InnerText);
}
```